# How to track location based iAd in iphone?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, iad

I need to how to track location based iAd.

For example if i'm in delhi, then how can i show, to track surrounding iAds upto 5km to show in my app. is this possible to show that? pls clear me

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: What do you mean track location based iAd? iAds will automatically use location to determine the right ads to be displayed. Do you want to see who is using your app within Delhi?

Comment: oh. anything changes in code  for show iAds or offers in application within particular range ? no need that.